# White balance algorithm

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, image-enhancement

I'm doing some image processing and I need an automatic white balancing algorithm that's not too intensive in terms of CPU computation time. Any recommendations?

EDIT: and if it's relevant to efficiency, I'll be implementing it in Java with color images as an array of integers.

Comment: some indication of the rabbit hole: https://www.eecs.yorku.ca/~mbrown/ICCV19_Tutorial_MSBrown.pdf

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A relatively simple algorithm is to average the hues (in HSV or HSL) of the brightest and darkest pixels on the screen. In a pinch, go with the brightest pixel only. If the hues between brightest and darkest are too different, go with the bright pixel. If the dark is near black go with the bright pixel.

Why even look at the dark pixel? Sometimes the dark is not near black, and hints at the ambient light or fog or haze.

This will make sense to you if you're a heavy Photoshop user. Highlights in a photo are unrelated (or weakly related) to the underlying color of the object. They are your best representation of the color cast of the light, unless the image is so overexposed that everything has overwhelmed the CCDs.

Then adjust the hues of all pixels.

You'll need fast RGB to HSV and HSV to RGB functions. (But maybe you can work in RGB for the pixel corrections with a LUT or linear interpolation.)

You don't want to go by average pixel color or most popular color. That way lies madness.

To quickly find the brightest color (and the darkest one), you can work in RGB, but you should have multipliers for green, red, and blue. On an RGB monitor, 255 green is brighter than 255 red which is brighter than 255 blue. I used to have good multipliers in my head, but alas, they have fled my memory. You can probably google for them.

This will fail in an image which has no highlights. A matte painted wall, for example. But I don't know what you can do about that.

---

There are many improvements to make to this simple algorithm. You can average multiple bright pixels, grid the image and grab bright and dark pixels from each cell, etc. You'll find some obvious tweaks after implementing the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try. i've also found a very simple algorithm that GIMP apparently uses for it's automatic white balancing, I'll bench mark the two algorithms and see which one is right for me :)

Comment: I would have thought that most photos would have at least 1 ultra-white pixel (255,255,255) – especially on lower quality cameras which often need more help with white-balance – and white pixels don't really help the algorithm at all.  So do you then look at the next brightest pixels?

Comment: @Simon, you can also take an average of the lightest and darkest N% of pixels.

Comment: You say "adjust the hues of all pixels", but I'm not sure what you mean by that. Once I know where the brightest pixel is, what do I do to the hues of all the other pixels?

Comment: @MattEllen That is probably too late, but I believe that what Nosredna meant by his phrase is the following: for the detected "white hue" (r_w,g_w,b_w) all pixels ought to be amplified by (1/r_w, 1/g_w, 1/b_w).

Comment: See the paper and code for Simplest Color Balance at: https://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2011/llmps-scb/article.pdf  It helps to put some of the above advice in context.

Answer (score 24):

GIMP apparently uses a very simple algorithm for automatic white balancing.
http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-layer-white-balance.html

> The White Balance command automatically adjusts the colors of the active layer by stretching the Red, Green and Blue channels separately. To do this, it discards pixel colors at each end of the Red, Green and Blue histograms which are used by only 0.05% of the pixels in the image and stretches the remaining range as much as possible. The result is that pixel colors which occur very infrequently at the outer edges of the histograms (perhaps bits of dust, etc.) do not negatively influence the minimum and maximum values used for stretching the histograms, in comparison with Stretch Contrast. Like “Stretch Contrast”, however, there may be hue shifts in the resulting image.

There is a bit more tweaking than is described here since my first attempt at implementing this works seems to work for most photos but other photos seem to have artifacts or contain too much of either red green or blue :/

Comment: Maybe you could implement multiple algorithms and then try to figure out which algorithm will work when, based on some characteristics of the images. For exposure (a rhather similar problem), modern cameras actually break the image up (plus they know focus point and like @Matthias Wandel pointed out, whether flash was used). Manufacturers have analyzed databases of many photos to see what works. First cameras I remember doing that were Nikon FA and a couple others of that era.

Comment: By the way, you can find the areas which are in focus by looking at maximum contrast between adjacent pixels. When a photographer uses flash, the in-focus area is usually relatively close to the camera and might have some nice highlights from the flash.

Comment: For the purpose of white balance, you probably care about the in-focus areas more than the out-of focus areas. So you can break the screen into, say 5x5 grid and "grade" the cells by focus and then weight them by importance for your white balance algorithm. I could shut up now if you want. Otherwise I'll probably keep babbling forever

Comment: Thanks Norsredna, I'm actually using this for video processing(which is why it needs to be efficient) so flash isn't an issue, but I can probably optimize by only recalculating white balancing parameters every 10 frames or so since lighting doesn't normally change that often. :P

Answer (score 12):

@Charles Ma has suggested to use the `Gimp` white balance algorithm. In `python` and `numpy` this could look like this:

```python
# white balance for every channel independently
def wb(channel, perc = 0.05):
    mi, ma = (np.percentile(channel, perc), np.percentile(channel,100.0-perc))
    channel = np.uint8(np.clip((channel-mi)*255.0/(ma-mi), 0, 255))
    return channel

image = cv2.imread("foo.jpg", 1) # load color
imWB  = np.dstack([wb(channel, 0.05) for channel in cv2.split(img)] )
```

it's fast, simple and provides pretty decent results

Answer (score 3):

White balancing algorithms are hard.  Even digital cameras get the wrong once in a while, even though they know a lot of extra info about the picture - such as whether the flash was used, and the light level.

For starters, I would just average red, green, and blue, and use that as the white balance point.  Set limits on it - stay within the ranges for tungsten, flourescent, and daylight.  It won't be perfect, but when its wrong, it will be relatively easy to explain why.

Comment: A popular first try, but that'll turn a red ball in the snow to a dullish red ball in a sea of cyan. It's worse than no white balance, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

One recently published algorithm is the Color Distribution algorithm:

> D. Cheng, D.K. Prasad, and M.S. Brown,
> "Illuminant Estimation for Color Constancy: Why spatial domain methods work and the role of the color distribution"
> Journal of the Optical Society of America A **31**(5):1049-1058 (2014)
> [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1364/JOSAA.31.001049), [PDF](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/%7Embrown/pdf/ColorConstancyJOSAv10.pdf)

In the paper there is also the reference to the [Matlab source code](https://web.archive.org/web/20180517130705/http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/%7Ewhitebal/illuminant/files/illuminantEstimator.m) (Internet Archive). It's a simple algorithm that can be easily programmed and the results show it to be very fast.

If you need additional fast and at the same time accurate white balancing (color constancy) algorithms, you should check [this site](http://www.fer.unizg.hr/ipg/resources/color_constancy/).

There are several algorithms with their respective source coded that might be just the ones you look for.

Comment: Recent work by M Afifi and M S Brown  is relevant and helpful:  https://github.com/mahmoudnafifi/WB_sRGB