# Auto White Balance, Auto Tone

Tags: image-processing

I came across to different search result from google or bing, I couldn't find a good example of adapting auto white balance for a bitmap file such as jpg.  My goal is to figure out how white balance algorithm works and how to adapt it using c#, java, or any programming language to achieve it.  If anyone could share some snippet or some resource, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: is it something you invented? bitmap file such as jpg?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175393/white-balance-algorithm

Answer (score 0):

The concept that is used in editing RAW format photos is the choose the whitest point in a photograph, then adjust to 255, 255, 255 ... but realistically, I adjust to around 240, 240, 240

I use Adobe bridge a lot for this

Comment: thanks, but i'm looking for code snippets.  I could do it in bridge or lightroom, but need this to be done on c# or java code.

Comment: take a look at Image Magik... you may be able to use it

Answer (score 0):

There's an [C# code here](https://adadevelopment.github.io/gdal/white-balance-gdal.html) for Gimp white balance algorithm. It is simple and fast.