# Calculate image whitebalance in PHP

Tags: php, image-processing

Im working on a script in PHP that compensates for whitebalance in an image.
I take a color sample from the white in the image but im not sure how I calculate the specific white balance.
I hope someone can help me!

regards,
Sander Mangel

Comment: Can you post what you have tried/researched up to now?

Comment: The only relevant script I found was on http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/whitebalance/index.php but im not able to translate it to PHP. There is nog a lot on this topic out there

Comment: possible duplicate of [White balance algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175393/white-balance-algorithm)

Comment: Hey @vascowhite I took a look at that duplicate article but I couldnt resolve my issue with it

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the function imagecolorforindex

Comment: Thanks Jordi, im indeed using this to get the RGB channels but I need a next step where I can calculate the white balance of the pixel I retrieved