# Remove the color temperature from a color value

Tags: image-processing, colors

Is it possible to ajust the RGB values if the light source is a warm white and not a cold white?

With the hardware we have, we have the information in the picture below.

[image: The data we have from the sensor]

Comment: Yes, white-balancing is possible in post. Use grey points (or which should be grey) in the image to find relationship between the components, then recalibrate/adjust from that.

Comment: This comment is more confusing than the question: "Yes, white-balancing is possible in post. Use grey points (or which should be grey) in the image to find relationship between the components, then recalibrate/adjust from that. " if you dont have the time to answer properly dont answer

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert your image from one colour temperature to another you need to apply colour correction! For that you need to compute the 3x3 Color correction matrix for that Temperature. You can have a rough idea about this [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/23999/mathematical-transfer-for-different-camera-attributes/24004#24004)

If you don't want to do this manually! You can go for Auto White Balance which will neutralize the overall effect of Color temperature as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175393/white-balance-algorithm)!